# How to get unique array of objects filtering by object key?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array of objects. Objects contain information about cities and their geometric info. here is my array

```
> [ {country: "AM", name: "Abovyan", lat: 40.27368, lng: 44.63348},
> {country: "AM", name: "Abovyan", lat: 40.04851, lng: 44.54742},
> {country: "AM", name: "Kapan", lat: 39.20755, lng: 46.4057} ]
```

As you can see i have 2 objects with the same name (e.g Abovyan) but their geometric info is different. This array i get from some API and i want to filter it . How can i filter it to have only one object with certain **key/value** , in this case with **name** ?

I would like to get a filtered array like this `

```
[ {country: "AM", name: "Abovyan", lat: 40.27368, lng: 44.63348},
  {country: "AM", name: "Kapan", lat: 39.20755, lng: 46.4057} ]
```

Comment: which value you want to keep for name Abovyan?

Comment: iterate throught the array ,create a empty object put the key as name and the value as the object, it will keep the last geometric info object .

Comment: I would like not to use an object .

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan its okay if you dont want to use an object , but you should mention that in the question descirption ,otherwise you see all the answer which you will get will be solved by object.

I am assuming you already have a solution using object and you are looking for possible solution without object

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use an object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here we build an object from the non-duplicate items using the `.name` property as the object key.  When we’re done we take the value array from that object.

```
var data = [ your data ];

var out = Object.values(
  data.reduce( (c, e) => {
    if (!c[e.name]) c[e.name] = e;
    return c;
  }, {})
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `Array.reduce()` for that output:

```js
var arr = [ {country: "AM", name: "Abovyan", lat: 40.27368, lng: 44.63348},{country: "AM", name: "Abovyan", lat: 40.04851, lng: 44.54742},
{country: "AM", name: "Kapan", lat: 39.20755, lng: 46.4057} ];
var res = arr.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
   var exist = acc.find(({country, name}) => obj.country === country && obj.name === name);
   if(!exist){
    acc.push(obj);
   }
   return acc;
},[]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could filter out the elements that do not already exist in a key:

```
 const unique = (arr, key) => {
   const keys = new Set();
   return arr.filter(el => !keys.has(el[key]) && keys.add(el[key]));
 };
```

So in your case you could use it as `unique([/*...*/, "name")`

Answer (score 3):

```
let materials = [
  {id: 1, name: "GALLERY PRINTS"},
  {id: 2, name: "GALLERY PRINTS"},
  {id: 3, name: "GALLERY PRINTS"},
  {id: 4, name: "FINE ART PRINTS"},
  {id: 5, name: "FINE ART PRINTS"}
]

let _materials = materials.filter((item, index, objects) => {
            if (index === 0) {
                return item;
            } else if (item.name !== objects[index - 1].name) {
                return item;
            }

        });

console.log(_materials);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Below code does a basic filter which is akin to a for..loop where you return true or false to remove or keep the item.

We can use the `map` method to create a temporary array, then we use the `indexOf` method to see if we can find the same object inside of our `map`. If we do, then we know it is a duplicate.

```js
var records = [ {country: "AM", name: "Abovyan", lat: 40.27368, lng: 44.63348},{country: "AM", name: "Abovyan", lat: 40.04851, lng: 44.54742},{country: "AM", name: "Kapan", lat: 39.20755, lng: 46.4057} ];
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
    return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    });
}


console.log(removeDuplicates(records,"name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
let person = [
  { group: 'A', name: 'Hello 1', age: 5 },
  { group: 'A', name: 'Hello 2', age: 6 },
  { group: 'B', name: 'Hello 3', age: 7 },
  { group: 'C', name: 'Hello 4', age: 5 },
  { group: 'B', name: 'Hello 5', age: 5 },
]
let uqiue_group = person.map(e => {
  return { group: e.group, name: e.name }
}).filter((element, index, array) => {
  return array.findIndex(a => a.group == element.group) === index
})

console.log(uqiue_group)
// output
// [
//   { group: 'A', name: 'Hello 1' },
//   { group: 'B', name: 'Hello 3' },
//   { group: 'C', name: 'Hello 4' }
// ]
```